# JKube maven plugin can't find jar file when building docker image using mvn k8s:build

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, fabric8, jkube

I'm trying to use [JKube](https://www.eclipse.org/jkube/) for building and deploying APIs to my K8S cluster but when I do `mvn k8s:build` I'm getting this error :

```
[INFO] --- kubernetes-maven-plugin:1.1.1:build (default-cli) @ trips-api ---
[INFO] k8s: Running in Kubernetes mode
[INFO] k8s: Building Docker image in Kubernetes mode
[INFO] k8s: [carpooling/trips-api:latest]: Created docker-build.tar in 2 seconds 
[ERROR] k8s: Failed to execute the build [Error while trying to build the image: Unable to build image [carpooling/trips-api:latest] : "COPY failed: no source files were specified" ]
```

This is the content of my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest
VOLUME /tmp
COPY target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

NB: I'm ensuring that under my target/ directory I have the right jar file.

Does anyone have an idea about why I'm getting this error ?

Comment: Hi, Plugin seems to be complaining for no deployment artifacts being present in `target/` directory. Are you sure you have done `mvn package` or `mvn clean install` for issuing `mvn k8s:build`?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share a reproducible project? Could you please join out chat https://gitter.im/eclipse/jkube

Comment: @RohanKumar I verified that target/ was not empty.
I just copied this thread into the discussion as you asked. How could I share a reproducible project ? Would you like to be added to my bitbucket ?

Comment: Np, let me try to prepare a reproducer and share it in case it's confidential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse JKube has an assembly mechanism for adding files to your container images. When using zero configuration Dockerfile mode, assembly name is set to `maven`. You would need to prefix your project files with `maven` to be able to access it. So your Dockerfile should look like this:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest
VOLUME /tmp
COPY maven/target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

I tested this with a simple demo project with your Dockerfile contents: https://github.com/r0haaaan/eclipse-jkube-spring-boot-simple-dockerfile and it seemed to work okay for me.